# Latex directives in template are causing `error in unicode escape`

Tags: templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to include some LaTEX code in play framework 2.0 template, namely:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
```

Of course play complains with `error in unicode escape` error message because of `\us...` parts.

How should I escape those pieces of text, so play compiles the template and I get verbatim LaTeX code in result? Tried my luck with @Html(), but it doesn't work either...

Comment: Did you try with double '\' ?

Comment: @nico_ekito yes, but it outputs double `\\` too, and that is not valid LaTeX

Comment: Do you need valid LaTex before or after template parsing?

Comment: Try by replacing the `\ ` using the HTML code: `&#92;`

Comment: @nico_ekito sorry, I didn't write it explicitly, but I'm looking for a solution that will give me verbatim LaTeX code. I'll update the question.

Comment: okay, sorry, I misunderstood :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an method ie in `Application.java` controller:

```
public static String latex(String s){
    return "\\"+s;
}
```

So you can use it in the view:

```
@Application.latex("usepackage[T1]{fontenc}")
@Application.latex("usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}")
@Application.latex("usepackage{babel}")
```

Comment: I have to admit that I expected there is more elegant solution. But looks like i can't have anything better than that. Thanks nevertheless! And ... joining the discussion: I prefer to have that code in scala to have better IDE features few keystrokes away ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or, based on @biesior answer, create a `latex.scala.html` file containing:

```
@(latexStatement:String)

@{
    "\\" + latexStatement
}
```

To use it:

```
@latex("usepackage[T1]{fontenc}")
@latex("usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}")
@latex("usepackage{babel}")
```

Comment: of course I don't want to deprecate your way :), anyway personally I prefer performing such formattings in Java instead of tags - it's definitely easier to keep control on wrapping spaces/empty lines. just my very humble opinion :)

Comment: sure, it is a matter of taste ;-) Personnaly, I prefer limiting the dependency from views to controller