# Play Framework with LaTex

Tags: playframework, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Latex directives in template are causing `error in unicode escape`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489262/latex-directives-in-template-are-causing-error-in-unicode-escape)

Im trying to add Latex to a view in a play application.
Can you point me some directions?
Thanks

Comment: I hardly believe that this question was asked just few days ago and it has accepted solution.

Comment: its not the same question. He already started it. I dont know how to start.

Comment: So if you want more details, you need write what exactly you are missing., what exactly you want to do etc.